# getting variable is undefined in javascript even with global variables

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined

I'm trying to do a memory game where the user will have a timer to find out where are pair of cards. Right now this is as basic as it gets, no timer, no random distribution of cards, i'm just trying to get the engine running and right now i'm getting stuck in the click event section. All i want to do right now is apply a CSS transform via javascript to the clicked card, I'm also open to suggestions on better ways to do this

**the HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Memória</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Cartas memória</h1>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS (checkout the last for loop)**

```
// Memoria

// criar array de simbolos 3 simbolos~repetidos 2 vezes
var simbolos = ["O","X","+","O","X","+"];
var jogo = {
    criarCartas: function () {
        var cartas = document.getElementsByClassName('carta');
        for ( i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++ ) {
            var carta = document.createElement('div');
            var front = document.createElement('div');
            var back = document.createElement('div');
            carta.className = "carta";
            front.className = "front";
            back.className = "back";
            document.body.appendChild(carta);
            carta.appendChild(front);
            carta.appendChild(back);
            //var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * simbolos.length);
            front.innerHTML = simbolos[i];
        }
        for ( j = 0 ; j < cartas.length ; j++ ) {
            cartas[j].onclick = function () {
                // cartas[j] will always be undefined in here, even with global variables or using this.cartas[j]
            };
        }
    }
};

// eventos

window.onload = function () {
    jogo.criarCartas();
};
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: verdana;
}

/* vai ser usado para efeitos hover */
.carta {
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 10px 10px;
}
/* affect all elmenents with class front and back inside all elements with class carta */
.carta > .front, .back {
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* define a posição inicial da carta*/
.front {
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    height: 180px;
    background-color: #FFFF99;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    perspective: 400px;
    transition: 1s ease;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* a traseira ja esta virada 180 graus */

.back {
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    height: 180px;
    background-color: #FF66CC;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    perspective: 400px;
    transition: 1s ease;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Your js is trying to grab carta class before it is created, try moving cartas declaration after the first for loop

Comment: Unless you haven't showed us the entire HTML, it's perfectly normal that `cartas[j]` is undefined. `cartas`, however, is just empty, not undefined. When you create this variable, no div with a class name `carta` exists.
You need create the variable after the DIVs are created (ie after your first `for` loop)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving cartas declaration to after the first for loop

```
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++ ) {
        var carta = document.createElement('div');
        var front = document.createElement('div');
        var back = document.createElement('div');
        carta.className = "carta";
        front.className = "front";
        back.className = "back";
        document.body.appendChild(carta);
        carta.appendChild(front);
        carta.appendChild(back);
        //var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * simbolos.length);
        front.innerHTML = simbolos[i];
    }
    var cartas = document.getElementsByClassName('carta');
```

Your current code is trying to grab the carta elements (before they are created and appended) which have not yet been created which is why it is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Acutally "this" (quite literally) was the solution :)

```
var simbolos = ["O","X","+","O","X","+"];
var jogo = {
    criarCartas: function () {  
        for ( i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++ ) {
            var carta = document.createElement('div');
            var front = document.createElement('div');
            var back = document.createElement('div');
            carta.className = "carta";
            front.className = "front";
            back.className = "back";
            document.body.appendChild(carta);
            carta.appendChild(front);
            carta.appendChild(back);
            //var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * simbolos.length);
            front.innerHTML = simbolos[i];
        }
        jogo.clicks();
    },
    clicks: function () {
        var cartas = document.getElementsByClassName('carta');
        for ( j = 0 ; j < cartas.length ; j++ ) {
            cartas[j].onclick = function () {
              this.childNodes[0].style.transform = (this.childNodes[0].style.transform != "rotateY(0deg)") ? "rotateY(0deg)" : "rotateY(180deg)";
              this.childNodes[1].style.transform = (this.childNodes[1].style.transform != "rotateY(180deg)") ? "rotateY(180deg)" : "rotateY(0deg)";
            };
        };
    }
};
```